# Create/call file with a variable name

Tags: python, file

I'm actually trying to program a sort of "rolegame", and actually I'm stuck in the process of creating the new Character files. I'm actually trying to make it so, if I call a character file, the system checks if it exists and, if not, it will create it. This is the code, just trying if it will create an empty file called `(charactername).char`:

```
import os
def call_char(name):
file = "%s.char" %name
if os.path.exists(file):
    print ("file loaded")
    open_char(file)
else:
    print ("creating new character")
    new_char(file)

"""creates a new character file"""
def new_char(file):
    print ("Character %s."%file)
    file(file, "w")

call_char("Volgrand")
```

However, I get this error while executing `call_char("Volgrand")`

```
  File "E:\python\Juego foral\test.py", line 51, in new_char
    file(file, "w")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"
```

I though that calling the variable `file` (a string) should work to create the new file.

Comment: In my life this is a first: I'd never heard of anyone trying to call a file. Please have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.python-course.eu/file_management.php) about file management and look online for more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in Python 2.x named [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file). However, by naming the *parameter* of the function `file`, you shadow that function, making it inaccessible. Imagine you call `new_char("foo")`, then the line in question becomes:

```
"foo"("foo", "w")
```

which pretty clearly makes absolutely no sense at all. Instead, you should:

1. Rename the parameter to the more sensible `filename`; and
2. Use the `open` context manager to open the file instead (per the documentation `open` is preferred to `file`, and using the `with` context manager form means you don't need to explicitly `close` the file).

This would give:

```
def new_char(filename):
    """creates a new character file"""
    print ("Character %s." % filename)
    with open(filename, "w"):
        pass
```

Note that I've also moved the docstring *inside the function*, where it belongs.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, and sorry for the extremely noob "oh-god-what-did-I-do-this-time" questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
def new_char(file):
    print ("Character %s."%file)
    file(file, "w")
```

You're naming the function parameter `file`, then trying to use the `file` built-in to open a file. First of all, you can't do that :). You shouldn't use the name of a built-in function for your variables, *especially* if you want to use that built-in; but really, don't do it anyway. Second of all, use `open`, not `file`.

Fixed code:

```
def new_char(filename):
    print ("Character %s." % filename)
    open(filename, "w")
```

There are other issues, such as the fact that you're not saving the file handle there, but that might be for another question.